# Remove downloads metabox in Woocommerce order edit pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, orders

I am trying to remove the 'woocommerce-order-downloads' div in the admin menu from the 'shop_order' context. I got a great answer to identify the context and was able to remove the 'postcustom' div with the following code. Note that I'm trying to the exact same thing by including a line to remove 'woocommerce-order-downloads' as well. That piece is not working. I've tried 'order-downloads', 'downloads', etc. I also went to Settings --> Account --> Blanked our 'downloads' route. This *seems* odd but I'm relatively new. Any ideas how to remove this pesky div? I'm also trying to remove the order_label div as well... As you can see :)

```
function remove_custom_field_meta_box()
{
    remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'shop_order', 'normal', 90);
    remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-downloads', 'shop_order', 'normal', 90);
    //remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-label', 'shop_order', 'normal');
}


//Remove postcustom/downloads/shippinglabel meta boxes
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_custom_field_meta_box');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'remove_shop_order_meta_boxe', 90 );
function remove_shop_order_meta_boxe() {
    remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'shop_order', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-downloads', 'shop_order', 'normal');
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.